# duplicate block device and UUID

Tags: block, device, uuid

Today I ran fsck on two partitions of our Ubuntu 16.04 server. Fsck has fixed various problems and afterwards I rebooted the server. After rebooting there were duplicate block device assignments with the same UUID, I don't have a clue where these come from. Example (output from `blkid`):

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="4689b1e7-beb7-446e-821d-96818f09de9b" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="users" PARTUUID="69d5f814-8f53-4022-801c-b02d574ae566"

/dev/sdd1: UUID="5712058e-1b7b-49f4-b615-aea6f7b6edae" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="data" PARTUUID="18dc9741-bd02-49f2-a300-cfeab6668a12"

/dev/sde1: UUID="f5c01709-1edd-4362-9b00-2a8e22cf6b0e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46b5062d-01"

/dev/sdf1: UUID="67ef1868-6a1c-4a1e-ba26-d12330529547" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="pilatus" PARTUUID="d062f971-bf1f-4946-b328-c9356faa0f88"

/dev/sdg1: UUID="57dbc614-c916-4d26-bb14-5192da619aa6" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="release" PARTUUID="252bbacc-1902-4dd1-9da6-e02f40352843"

/dev/sdh1: UUID="4689b1e7-beb7-446e-821d-96818f09de9b" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="users" PARTUUID="69d5f814-8f53-4022-801c-b02d574ae566"

/dev/sdi1: UUID="5712058e-1b7b-49f4-b615-aea6f7b6edae" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="data" PARTUUID="18dc9741-bd02-49f2-a300-cfeab6668a12"

/dev/sdj1: UUID="f5c01709-1edd-4362-9b00-2a8e22cf6b0e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="46b5062d-01"

/dev/sdk1: UUID="67ef1868-6a1c-4a1e-ba26-d12330529547" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="pilatus" PARTUUID="d062f971-bf1f-4946-b328-c9356faa0f88"

/dev/sdl1: UUID="57dbc614-c916-4d26-bb14-5192da619aa6" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="release" PARTUUID="252bbacc-1902-4dd1-9da6-e02f40352843"
```

e.g. `/dev/sdj1`, `/dev/sdk1` and `/dev/sdl1` appeared after the reboot.

The physical drives are attached to a storage server via iSCSI. What could be the reason for this and how can these devices be removed?

Comment: Is this a multipath setup?

Comment: Not as far as I know, at least it should not be. These 3 new drives /dev/sdi1, /dev/skl1 and /dev/sdl have been added without any explicit action. The server is running for a few years now and these drive did not exist and seem to have been created after a reboot. Before the reboot two partitions have been fixed with fsck.